# Magento admin page blank after login

Tags: magento

My magento version 1.8.0.1 website admin panel shows a BLANK Page after login in. until 2-3 days ago its worked perfectly; I made no changes in any file related to my website. 
Could anybody tell me that what's going on with my website & what is the cause of this problem.

An image of the blank page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmskn.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: edited grammar, and the question link.

Comment: I agree with @enigmativity, ask magento.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Flush your magento root `/var/cache` folder and `/var/session` folders, It may have previous server session that may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

To rectify this problem:

- Login to database via phpmyadmin or any other mysql client.
- Open **core_config_data** table.
- Find entry with path like `dev/log/active`.
- Set its value to **1**.
- Delete **/var/session** and **/var/cache** folders in your installation.
- Retry to login to admin panel.
- If problem is related to functionality, there will be log files in **/var/log** folder.

You can trace cause of problem from log files of magento.

Please let me know if you find any difficulty.